# Creating a web application to concatenate strings to unify naming conventions

Tags: web-development, javascript, html, development-approach

I've been tasked with creating a small web application, where users have a series of forms (I can't currently think of a better way of doing this) which will contain, either a)text input fields or b)drop down lists. The form will look as follows:

`form1`
`input box input box drop down box`

`form2`
`input box input box drop down box input box`

`form3`
`input box dropdown box input box drop down box`

Now for each form, I would need to concatenate the resulting string stored within each box (drop down or input). Seems fairly simple and I already have a working prototype. Problem is for each form there can be multiple rows.

What would be the easiest way to approach this? My skills are limited to HTML, CSS, JavaScript and some (light) JQuery. The working prototype I currently have the user fills out all the fields and then presses a "generate" button which generates all the conctenated strings. Is this approach that you would take?

Answer (score 2):

I think for this kind of application, a generate button would probably be undesirable from a UX perspective, especially if the operation performed is as trivial as you make it sound.

Here's what I hacked together in a few minutes, for what I think you are approximately describing:

http://jsfiddle.net/qtY38/4/

(Is jsfiddle still en-vogue?)

The meat being:

```
function processRecords (form){    
    var result="";

    var inputs = form.elements;
    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; ++i){
        var input = inputs[i];
        result += input.value;
    }

    var target = document.getElementById(form.dataset.target);
    target.textContent = result;
}
```

The nice thing about this function is that it assumes nothing about your form other than the fact that it has inputs, and a data-target attribute with the id of the element you want to populate with the result. In addition, it's so cheap to run, that you can do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/CBjPL/1/

The difference being I've removed all submit buttons and added the following snippet:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var forms = document.forms;
    for(var i=0; i<forms.length; ++i){
        processRecords(forms[i]);
    }
}, 100);
```

Which just automagically actively updates the outputs no matter how the user updates them. This is faster/easier for the user, and as a bonus has a better "wow factor" for the higher-ups.

This may seem kind of wasteful, actively looping and updating text areas that aren't changing, but listening for input changes is kind of a tedious thing in HTML, and this gets the job done easily for moderately sized pages. Especially since all you're doing is walking around the DOM and fiddling with rows. There's probably an optimization to be had in not updating the DOM if you don't have to, but it's not clear to me that that would even be worth it for such a trivial computation. Optimize second!

I'm not sure what you're referring to with respect to "multiple rows per form". If you mean you want to embed multiple collections of inputs/outputs in one  element, my gut reaction is... why? As described, you don't really seem to be using the forms as anything other than a trivial wrapper, and it's not like  elements introduce a massive overhead.

Answer (score -4):

Using JavaScript can perfectly do your job.

Comment: The OP is *already* using JavaScript. Your answer lacks all detail as to *how* the OP could solve the problem or why his approach is a good idea or not.